# Tmux not detaching, sending keys from script

Tags: tmux, bash

I have a remote server that I can reboot remotely, and I'm trying to make a script that starts my RESTful service. The script is called from `.bash_profile`. It starts it correctly, but it stays attached to the new tmux session, and hangs until I ssh in and manually detach it. Currently I'm sending `C-b d` but it doesn't detach.

Here is my small script:

```
tmux new-session -s cf
tmux send-keys -t cf 'cd ~/server' C-m
tmux send-keys -t cf 'sudo ./gradlew jettyRun' C-m
tmux send-keys -t cf 'C-b d'
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: do you know about `nohup myCmd &` ? Search here and read a few questions that include `nohup`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

you can detach the session when creating it using -d :

```
tmux new-session -ds cf
```

and then you can access it anyway